# Why I see (Paste from Other Apps) permission in my app setting page

Tags: ios, firebase-dynamic-links

In my iOS app, I saw a setting for Paste from Other Apps. And whenever I open the application, a popup shows to allow paste from other apps. How to disable this programmatically?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't, Apple started this 1 or 2 OSs ago.

Comment: @loremipsum Other apps has no features like this, why I'm getting it while other no !!

Comment: Your app is trying to access the contents of the clipboard. If it doesn't do that then it won't get the message.

Comment: @Paulw11 Is there any way to prevent my app trying to access the content of clipboard?

Comment: It's your app; you need to work out where it is doing it.